# define environment variable in WebSphere for dev and prod env

Tags: java, environment-variables, websphere, war

I want to check do we have environment variable concept in Websphere server for define username, password or some parameter outside of war file? I don't want to change the mentioned details when I am deploying my codes for prod env. 
So would you advise me how to do this with WebSphere server? my application is in Java.

I am sure that in AWS servers we have this concept to define environment parameter but do we have same in WebSphere also? I am using WebSphere version 8.5. Is there a best practice to maintain when we talk about environment variables?

Comment: The operating system. Windows, Linux, mac, or BSD.... all have environment variables. Personally, I like [dotenv](https://github.com/cdimascio/java-dotenv).

Comment: Traditional WAS does support defining envars for managed servers, although we'll need more details to say if your use of envars is a good practice or not: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/urun_environment_entries.html